# How to set Golang's log output back to console?

Tags: logging, go, console, output, reset

Google Go's `log` package has [SetOutput](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput) - a function for setting the log output to any io.Writer. After I set it for testing, I would like to revert the output back to the standard console output - how do I do that? I don't see any obvious way of resetting it in the `log` or `io` packages.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

For standard error (the default):

```
log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
```

For standard output:

```
log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
```

http://golang.org/src/log/log.go